# no window borders, can't see Unity, uninstall Mint skin

Tags: unity, compiz, themes, uninstall

I have no windows borders. It is probably a compiz fusion issue. But I don't know how to uninstall that.

[image: screenshoot]

I can't see Unity, it worked in 12.04 but not on 12.10 or 13.04. And I want to uninstall the Linux Mint theme/skin which has never looked right. up until oddly enough 13.04 in which it looks ok.

Can I just clean install the 13.04 without wiping the whole hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a window compositor problem, maybe it's a setting 'Don't show window borders.' or 'Don't show window title.'

Try the CompizConfig Settings Manager.
Is the 'Window Decoration' module enabled?
And restore the values, to the default settings.

When I switch that Window Decoration module off, I have the same windows as in your picture :-)

Comment: ok I removed compiz entirely. I have the windows boards and controls back. still need to figure out how to uninstall mint theme and get Unity back.